# Defining custom callbacks for a node function

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous, callback

So I've got a function which reads a bunch of data from about 500 different links and saves that data to a file, a process which takes a few seconds. The trick is, I'd like to start manipulating that data once the fetch is completed, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I know that if i was doing a basic http.get call I could just use the built in callback function, but this is a custom function that I've created, so how do I do a callback for when the whole process is over?

I've read that I can define a callback to pass to my function and call at the end of my function, but that seems to just run on a different thread, instead of waiting for my data to complete before running.

Any advice would be apprecaited, hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you have something like this, right?

```
http.get('something', function(data) { ... });
```

and you want to change that function to something custom you've written before.

So try this:

```
function myFunction(data) { ... }
http.get('something', myFunction);
```

or perhaps:

```
var myFunction = function(data) { ... };
http.get('something', myFunction);
```

Hopefully I've understood?